# バリデートで下記のエラーが出ます。なぜ出るのでしょうか？

Tags: html5

バリデートで下記のエラーが出ます。なぜ出るのでしょうか？
doctype宣言、charsetはあるのですが、なぜ出るのでしょうか？

そういえばファイヤーバグの`<!DOCTYPE html>`が灰色になっています。

> Error: The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using
>   windows-1252.
>
> Error: Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected e.g.
>   `<!DOCTYPE html>`. From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 6
>   `<html><body>`
>
> Error: Element head is missing a required instance of child element
>   title. From line 1, column 7; to line 1, column 12

ソース

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ああああああ</title>
        ～
    </head>
```

Comment: バリデータはソースの一行目が `<html><body>` だと言っているわけですから、何らかの原因でバリデートする前にソースコードが改変されているのかもしれないですね。何にせよ、バリデータとして何をどのように使っているのか、といった情報は必要だと思います。

Comment: 第三者が問題を再現できるように、具体的なやり方を示してくださいませんか？　HTML のバリデータにもいくつかあるので、何もなしだと分かりません。

Comment: ソースコードは、選択した上で編集画面の `{}` を押すか、行頭に4つスペースを入れることでブロック装飾できます。今後お試しください。

Comment: w3cのバリデータです。ただ不思議なことに直接ソースを張り付けたところエラーが出ませんでした、もしかするとlv9というレンサバの問題でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やはりサーバの問題のようです。他のサイトでも同じ問題が起きました。lv9には気を付けないといけないですね。今後の方の参考になれば幸いです。
ソースを張り付けると問題は起きませんでした。